# Where to create music player service w.r.t. MediaBrowserServiceCompat

Tags: java, android, mediabrowserservicecompat

I want to create a MusicPlayer application which leverages the features of [MediaBrowserService](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app.html).
While going thru documentation of [MediaBrowserServiceCompat](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice.html), I realized it is a subclass of [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), which means it runs on Application's main UI thread.

But since music player is a long running task, I suppose its best to implement it as an `IntentService`, rather than as Service.

So I wanted to ask:

1. Where should I implement my MusicPlayer service?
2. Should I implement it within `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` implementation? But will it not make too heavy on UI thread?
3. Or should I implement it as an `IntentService` & call it from my MediaBrowserServiceCompat? But it seems bit complex.

Here is my initial [code structure](https://github.com/overflowst/MyApplication.git)

Please suggest.

*Thank You*

Answer (score 1):

The music player I wrote uses background service from which I play the songs.

The problem with this approach is that on devices like Xiaomi or Huawei those services are killed in order to "save" battery life. I guess the best you can do is when your service gets killed you could restart it and start the song again ...

That's the solution I came up with, if anyone has a better idea I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Service as a command manager for your music player app. All the play, pause, next and other playback controls should be sent to service, and service will delegate it accordingly. Also Android [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) has asynchronous methods and associated listeners to notify callers. Please do have a look at [it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).
Please follow google sample code for music player https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer which addresses basic music player functionalities very well.

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong :**

> I realized it is a subclass of Service, which means it runs on
>   Application's main UI thread.

**Doc clearly say :**

> A [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is an application component that can perform long-running
>   operations in the background

And it also said if you need some kind of long time task, you should implement as **[Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)**.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

Notification notification =
          new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_DEFAULT_IMPORTANCE)
    .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_title))
    .setContentText(getText(R.string.notification_message))
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setTicker(getText(R.string.ticker_text))
    .build();

startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Document also says: 'Remember that if you do use a service, it still runs in your application's main thread by default, so you should still create a new thread within the service if it performs intensive or blocking operations'.... But using an intent service is much easier than starting a new thread in service, which does the same task.